# Customizable modular GUI developed in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, customization, modularity

For my final project in a bachelor's degree I want to develop an instant messenger with a fully customisable GUI. I hope to have an application with modular components that can be added and removed at will, and shifted around the window as desired (sort of like how you can move components within Visual Studio 2010).
If anyone has any resources or helpfull research topics they can point me towards it would be a great help in getting me on my feet with this project.

Comment: Your question is unclear on one point. Are you looking for the users to be able to move components, or are you looking to do this during development?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I wasn't sure on how to phrase my questions. I want users to be able to move components, with dockable frames and the like.
I came across one example this morning. Try running this java app and dragging the GUI around if you still don't know what I mean. http://dock.javaforge.com/screenshots.html

Answer (score 1):

**[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)** (the ui toolkit used to build the Eclipse IDE) and the **[Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)** have full support for dockable containers - that's the toolkit you want to use!

Answer (score 1):

The [Netbeans Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) is a fully fledged application framework, used as a base for the Netbeans editor.